# Filter out previously selected assets from employee view in Odoo 11

Tags: python-2.7, odoo-10, openerp-8

In employee form view I have a **asset_ids** One2many field to **'account.asset.asset'**.

When I want to add a new asset to an employee, the asset which was already assigned to an employee is also shown in the list. How can I only show unallocated assets in employee form view?

**Code Sample**

```
class HrEmployee(models.Model):
_inherit = ['hr.employee']

asset_ids = fields.One2many('account.asset.asset','employee_id', string='Assets Owned')


class AccountAssetAsset(models.Model):
_inherit = ['account.asset.asset']

employee_id = fields.Many2one('hr.employee', string="Employee")
```

Can this be done using domain filters?

Comment: your field is one2many so when you say i don't want the selected assest to be shown i'm assuming that you talk about a many2one field in account.asset.asset ?

Comment: @Tchi-Odoo Yea. But I add assets from employee form view. So when I click on the Assets Owned it will display all the assets which I have created. In that list, those assets which are already allocated are also shown. So how can we filter out those selected assets from the list, when I am in Employee form (One2many to account.asset.asset).